# Write a convert function with Pipeline

Tags: python

Write a convert function so that given a list of integers, the function will check for each of the numbers in the list whether the number is a correct score between 0 and 100. If so, the function, will assign it to one of the following categories:

- A If the number is between 91 and 100.
- B if the number is between 81 and 90.
- C if the number is between 71 and 80.
- D If the number is between 56 and 70.
- Fail if a score is lower than 56.

Example output:

```
 (('A:', [98]),('B:', [90, 81]),('D:', [68, 63, 61]),('Fail:', [20, 45, 3]))
```

What do I need to complete the task?

```
    def convert(list1):
    A = tuple(filter(lambda x:100>=x>=91 ,list1))
    B = tuple(filter(lambda x:81<=x<=90 ,list1))
    C = tuple(filter(lambda x:71<=x<=80 ,list1))
    D = tuple(filter(lambda x:56<=x<=70 ,list1))
    E = tuple(filter(lambda x:0<=x<=56 ,list1))

    x = zip(['A:', 'B:', 'D:', 'Fail:'], ([A], [B], [D], [E]))
    x = filter(lambda x: len(x)>0  , x)
    return tuple(x)

lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
```

The output is:

```
(('A:', [(98,)]), ('B:', [(90, 81)]), ('D:', [(68, 63, 61)]), ('Fail:', [(20, 45, 3)]))
```

Comment: Instead of `tuple(x)` return something else, where the string `'A:'` is combined with the tuple `A`, and so on. Also, your tuples `A`, `B`, etc., should be lists.

Comment: To add to @mkrieger1, a dictionary would probably be a better choice here, unless your instructor insists on using tuples.

Comment: You just need to add to each tuple it's letter: `A = ('A', list(filter(lambda x:x>91 , list)))` (the name of the argument shouldn't be `list` of course for that to work)

Comment: I re-updated the exercise and you will see what the output is

Answer (score 2):

With few modifications of your code

- use `<=` instead of `<`, because for now your excluding value like 90 and 91
- use `zip` with `ABCDE` to get the final result

```
def convert(list):
    A = tuple(filter(lambda x: 91 <= x <= 100, list))
    B = tuple(filter(lambda x: 81 <= x <= 90, list))
    C = tuple(filter(lambda x: 71 <= x <= 80, list))
    D = tuple(filter(lambda x: 56 <= x <= 70, list))
    E = tuple(filter(lambda x: 0 <= x <= 56, list))
    return tuple(zip(['A:', 'B:', 'C:', 'D:','Fail:'], (A, B, C, D, E)))


lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
# (('A', (98,)), ('B', (90, 81)), ('C', ()), ('D', (68, 63, 61)), ('E', (20, 45, 3)))
```

---

Here's how I would have done it

```
def grade(x):
    if 91 <= x <= 100:
        return 'A'
    if 81 <= x <= 90:
        return 'B'
    if 71 <= x <= 80:
        return 'C'
    if 56 <= x <= 70:
        return 'D'
    if 0 <= x <= 56:
        return 'Fail'
    return None  # handle negative and >100 values

def convert(values):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for value in values:
        g = grade(value)
        if g:
            result[g + ":"].append(value)
    return sorted(result.items())

lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
# [('A:', [98]), ('B:', [90, 81]), ('D:', [68, 63, 61]), ('Fail:', [20, 45, 3])]
```