# how to Removing an empty tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Removing an empty tuple for example the empty c organ and I do not want it to appear in the output

```
def convert(list1):
    A = tuple(filter(lambda x:100>=x>=91 ,list1))
    B = tuple(filter(lambda x:81<=x<=90 ,list1))
    C = tuple(filter(lambda x:71<=x<=80 ,list1))
    D = tuple(filter(lambda x:56<=x<=70 ,list1))
    E = tuple(filter(lambda x:0<=x<=56 ,list1))
    x = zip(['A:', 'B:','C', 'D:', 'Fail:'], ([A], [B],[C], [D], [E]))
    return tuple(x)
lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
```

my output is: `(('A:', [(98,)]), ('B:', [(90, 81)]), ('C', [()]), ('D:', [(68, 63, 61)]), ('Fail:', [(20, 45, 3)]))`

its should be like this: `(('A:', [(98,)]), ('B:', [(90, 81)]), ('D:', [(68, 63, 61)]), ('Fail:', [(20, 45, 3)]))`

Comment: You want to have tuples in one-item lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a convert function with Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70227931/write-a-convert-function-with-pipeline)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to use Python tuple comprehension expression.

change your return statement to this

```
return tuple((i, [j]) for (i, [j]) in tuple(x) if j)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be check the length of the tuple inside that list, change your return statement to:

```
return tuple((i, j) for i, j in x if len(j[0]) > 0)
```

Or even simpler check the truthiness of the tuple:

```
return tuple((i, j) for i, j in x if j[0])
```

Or Using `filter`:

```
return tuple(filter(lambda x: x[1][0], x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(tuple([t for t in convert(lst) if t[1] != [()]]))
```

gives output:

```
(('A:', [(98,)]), ('B:', [(90, 81)]), ('D:', [(68, 63, 61)]), ('Fail:', [(20, 45, 3)]))
```