# I need to connect tuple

Tags: python

I need to connect a, b, c, d and add the letters at the beginning of each tuple
Is an example of my code with a zip function **but must not use zip functions**
These are just map, filter, tuple I would love to help with output of this kind
(('A:', [98]), ('B:', [90, 81]), ('D:', [68, 63, 61]), ('Fail:', [20, 45] , 3]))

I need a replacement for the zip algorithm

```
def convert(list1):
    A = tuple(filter(lambda x:100>=x>=91 ,list1))
    B = tuple(filter(lambda x:81<=x<=90 ,list1))
    C = tuple(filter(lambda x:71<=x<=80 ,list1))
    D = tuple(filter(lambda x:56<=x<=70 ,list1))
    E = tuple(filter(lambda x:0<=x<=56 ,list1))
    #x = zip(['A:', 'B:','C', 'D:', 'Fail:'], ([A], [B],[C], [D], [E]))

    return tuple(filter(lambda x: x[1][0], x))

lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
```

Comment: Why did you open another question? [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234467/how-to-removing-an-empty-tuple)

Comment: Why shouldn't you use `zip`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Removing an empty tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234467/how-to-removing-an-empty-tuple)

Comment: @KlausD. The one you call original is actually a duplicate in itself of [this original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70227931/write-a-convert-function-with-pipeline)...

Comment: your last condition (for E) should be `0<=x<=55` otherwise a score of 56 will appear in two places.

Answer (score 0):

The output of filter is an iterator.  You would need to convert it to a list to get the second part of your tuples.

Given that you have a relatively limited number of keys, the function could build the output tuple directly without using zip:

```
def convert(list1):
    A = list(filter(lambda x:100>=x>=91 ,list1))
    B = list(filter(lambda x:81<=x<=90 ,list1))
    C = list(filter(lambda x:71<=x<=80 ,list1))
    D = list(filter(lambda x:56<=x<=70 ,list1))
    E = list(filter(lambda x:0<=x<=55 ,list1))
    R = ( ('A:',A), ('B:',B), ('C:',C), ('D:',D), ('Fail:',E) )
    return tuple(filter(lambda t: t[1], R))
```

Output:

```
lst = (20, 45, 90, 3, 68, -30, 81, 98, 104, 63, 61)
print(convert(lst))
(('A:', [98]), ('B:', [90, 81]), ('D:', [68, 63, 61]), ('Fail:', [20, 45, 3]))
```

You could also avoid the merging issue altogether by assigning the key and list as tuples in your 5 variables:

```
def convert(list1):
    A = ('A:',list(filter(lambda x:100>=x>=91 ,list1)))
    B = ('B:',list(filter(lambda x:81<=x<=90 ,list1)))
    C = ('C:',list(filter(lambda x:71<=x<=80 ,list1)))
    D = ('D:',list(filter(lambda x:56<=x<=70 ,list1)))
    E = ('Fail:',list(filter(lambda x:0<=x<=55 ,list1)))
    return tuple(filter(lambda t: t[1], (A,B,C,D,E)))
```

If you are allowed to use a for-loop, the function could be implemented more efficiently:

```
def convert(list1):
    R = (("",[]),("A:",[]),("B:",[]),("C:",[]),("D:",[]),("Fail:",[]),("",[]))
    for x in list1:
        i = (x<0) + (x<56) + (x<71) + (x<81) + (x<91) + (x<101)
        R[i][1].append(x)
    return tuple(filter(lambda t: t[0] and t[1], R))
```

Instead of going through the values 5 times, you can prepare a resulting tuple (R) with the keys and lists initialized ahead of time. Then compute an index at which to add each score. The resulting tuple is setup with an extra "bucket" at the beginning and end to capture out of bounds values without requiring special conditions in the loop.

To determine the index, the limit values of ranges are compared to the score counting 1 for each range that ends above the score value.  So, for example, a score of 75 will go at index 3 because `(x<0) + (x<56) + (x<71) + (x<81) + (x<91) + (x<101)` will produce `(0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1)` (given that True is 1 and False is 0)